# Types of UML diagram - VISIO - ASP.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, uml, visio

Below, I have an extract from a design specification and need to create UML diagrams as .NET specifications. No coding is yet started or is there any solution structure yet. What would be best highlevel UML diagrams for such scenarios (by not including any class diagrams)?

**Example scenario**

Display Drop Zone Queue

The following steps are to be performed at this point:

1.Display the contents of the `DZ_JOB_CONTAINER` (`DZ-CT-JCON`) entity in a new browser window. This is to be done as follows.

a. Read DZ-CT-JCON entity where

- job_type = “A” (i.e. Acquisition records only)
- job_status < 29 (i.e. not a deleted entry). Note: This field is only to be included in the selection criteria where the user has selected to not display deleted records. This is to be the default setting when the queue is initially displayed.
- current_flag = “Y” (i.e. “Active entries only)

Note 1: Display only Drop Zone queue records which have not been fully processed (that is, transferred successfully to the BI job queue).

Note 2: The `DZ-CT-JCON` entity is to be sorted in the following sequence: Job Type, Data Stream ID, Data Stream Provider Code, Container Sequence Number

b. For each record found matching these selection criteria, the following fields are to be displayed.

- Data Stream – the data stream description from the CTRL_DATA_STREAM entity is to be displayed instead of the data stream ID.
- Data Stream Provider Code
- Container Sequence Number
- Container Start Date. Format: DD/MM/YYYY
- Container End Date. Format: DD/MM/YYYY
- Container Generation Date. Format: DD/MM/YYYY
- Job Status – the job status description from the CTRL_JOB_STATUS entity is to be displayed instead of the job status id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Activity Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram) are a good high level diagram choice.  The example has a some very low level details which would also lean toward a combination of class diagrams and [sequence diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram), but the no class diagram constraint excludes that choice.

Below is a rough activity diagram.

[activity diagram http://home.comcast.net/~ga1/SO1685438_a.png](http://home.comcast.net/~ga1/SO1685438_a.png)

Comment: Thanks G_A.  As am bit new to Visio, if this need to be done as sequence diagram how could this be done.  Can you please show me a sample of this using the example provided.  thanks

Comment: Sequence diagrams method calls between objects so would require class diagram level detail.  I'll add an activity diagram shortly.